# Native Client for Screen Capture

Tags: c++, screen-capture, google-nativeclient

I am studying Chrome extensions that do screen recording and make videos out of them. I can not understand how they work yet but I found a common pattern among them all.

They all have a file called `video_encoder_main-x86-64.nexe` and `castify_edit_main-x86-64.nexe` which I can not find both them.

I was wondering if anyone who worked before with a similar case where a native client is collecting screen capture to make a webm video or mp4 that I can upload to YouTube.

I want this project to prove a concept for a training company that want to upload screen capture of students solving homework.

Comment: have you googled "castify"? One of the first results I get is "screencastify".

Comment: I did, I thought this file is something screencastify wrote, but I found the same file within two other extensions but I could not find the sources or any mention of how it was developed